# Отличить присвоенный NULL у элемента массива, от несуществующего элемента

Tags: php

Возможно ли отличить присвоенный NULL у элемента массива, от несуществующего элемента?

```php
$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$array[3] = null;

echo "<pre>";

echo "is_null -> 5  "; var_dump(is_null($this->params[5])); // [1] true
echo "is_null -> 3  "; var_dump(is_null($this->params[3])); // [2] true
echo "isset -> 5  ";   var_dump(isset($this->params[5]));   // [3] false
echo "isset -> 3  ";   var_dump(isset($this->params[3]));   // [4] false
echo "count  ";        var_dump(count($this->params));      // [5] 4
print_r($array);                                            // [6]

echo "</pre>";
```

С результатами `>[1...3]`, все понято. Почему у `>[4] false`? При этом `>[5] count = 4`, так же если распечатать массив, третий элемент существует, но ничему равен:

```
// >[6]

array(4) {
  [0]=>
    string(1) "a"
  [1]=>
    string(1) "b"
  [2]=>
    string(1) "c"
  [3]=>
    NULL
}
```

Comment: а зачем превращать null в стринг? И причем здесь БД, в которой элемент всегда есть, при условии что строка есть?

Comment: @Ипатьев, что бы отличить пустое поле от несуществующего, вряд ли понадобится так делать, пример с бд просто для добавления предметности

Comment: если конкретно для элементов массива то есть array_key_exists. А если для переменных, то наверное никак. только через отлов ошибки наверное

Comment: я не полнимаю такой "предметности", которая ссылается на случай, который "вряд ли когда-нибудь встретится"

Comment: @Ипатьев Справедливо, скорректировал вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев Надо ли оформить ответ, на основе вашего комментария? могу ли это сделать сославшись на ваш комментарий?

Comment: Можно даже не ссылаясь. Я так и не смог найти нормального вопроса чтобы закрыть как дубликат, все вопросы дурацкие про какие-то частности. только нормальный ответ, с кодом, который четко показывает что вот этого элемента нет совсем, а вот этот есть но равен нулл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `isset()` - возвращает `true` если все переданные аргументы определены и не равны `null`
2. `is_null()` - возвращает `true` если переданный аргумент равен `null`
3. `array_key_exists()`  - возвращает `true` если в массиве существует элемент с указанным индексом

Answer (score 1):

> если конкретно для элементов массива то есть array_key_exists. А если для переменных, то наверное никак. только через отлов ошибки наверное

```php
function array_val($array, $i){
  if(array_key_exists($i, $array)){
    if(is_null($array[$i])){
       echo "array[$i] = null";
    }else{
       echo "array[$i] = {$array[$i]}";
    }
  }else{
    echo "Элемент $i не существует";
  }
}

$array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
$array[3] = null;

array_val($array, 3); // array[3] = null
array_val($array, 5); // Элемент 5 не существует
array_val($array, 1); // array[1] = b
```